# Submiting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like to create form with xy results

For example checking 'A' alone may produce result 1, while if both 'A' and 'B' are checked then the answer is result 2. D,E,A may give result 3 while B,E,A give result 2. Hopefully you get the point.

```
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="A" />Choice A<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="B" />Choice B<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="C" />Choice C<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="D" />Choice D<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="E" />Choice E<br />   
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="answer">
```

and the jquery would be something along these lines

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
var value = $(this).val();

if ($(this).val(["A","B","C"]).is(':checked'))
    $('.result1').show(value);
else
    $('.result1').hide(value);

if ($(this).val(["A","D","E"]).is(':checked'))
    $('.result2').show(value);
else
    $('.result2').hide(value);
```

This don't work so if you could help me it would be great!

Comment: Whats doesn't work ? Nothing shows up ? Bad result ? Be more precise.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bUdra/ here is example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, given A, B and C you want to do something. Which is different to A, B and E which might do something else. I've come up with this:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
    var checkedBoxes = $(':checked');
    var values = new Array();
    $.each(checkedBoxes, function(index, value) {
        var checkboxValue = $(value).val();
        values.push(checkboxValue);
    });

    if (containsOnly(values, ['A', 'B', 'C'])) {
        alert('Hi');
    }
    if (containsOnly(values, ['A', 'D', 'E'])) {
        alert('Bye');
    }
});

function containsOnly(needles, haystack){ 
    if (needles.length !== haystack.length) {
        return false;
    }
    var result = _.intersection(needles, haystack).length === haystack.length;
    return result;
}
```

So, what this does is it grabs all the checked checkboxes and then grabs the values contained within. Once it has the values, it compares them using UnderscoreJS's (underscorejs.org) intersection. That means we can check to see if (and only if) ALL of the values are contained within the array.

Once the check is complete and if it satisfies the conditions, it will do something.

Also, why underscore js? It provides a lot of really useful LINQ-like expressions for javascript and it saves you reinventing the wheel. Definitely worthwhile for iterator functions because it saves you time and effort.

As always, Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/bUdra/5/

Hope this helps

Comment: No, form that i'm working on is about heating systems so example is if i select A,B,C then form must show me scheme4 or if i select A,D,E then must show me scheme 6.. I hope you understand me

Comment: Yup, gotcha. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot! that is what i have been looking for Kyle :)

Comment: @LukaVugrač please see the edit, there was an issue with the previous code which meant that it wasn't entirely correct. Also, if this question helped you please mark it as the answer. Glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: here i marked your anwser.. Just a side question do you know how i could change alert box that don't display text, i wanna display image it can be in different page or somethin

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question fully. If you wanted to put an image in an alert, it's not possible.

Comment: sorry about my bad english my question was can i change alert with image example:
    if (containsOnly(values, ['A', 'D', 'E'])) {
        alert('Bye');

i wanna change alert with image can i do that somehow? or can i add link somewhere?

Comment: You could add your link\image\whatever to a div or something like that? look at `.html()` http://api.jquery.com/html/